# How to run TestNG tests one-by-one

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, testng

I have a test suite and I want to run tests form XML file one-by-one. But when I'm running it, it runs all TCs at the same time (I have 3 open browsers at the same time).

My XML:

```
    <suite name="TestingSuite" preserve-order="true" parallel="false" verbose="10">
      <test name="Test1">
         <classes>
            <class name="guiAndFunctianal.LoginFail" />
            <class name="guiAndFunctianal.LoginAsManager" />
            <class name="guiAndFunctianal.CreateUserTest" />        
          </classes>
      </test>
    </suite>
```

My TCs looks like this:

```
    public class LoginFail extends AbstractTest{ 
    @ BeforeTest 
    public void openBrowser() {
     openBrowserFireFoxAllTcs();
     } 
    @ Test
     public void main (){   
    }
    @ AfterTest 
    public void quit() { 
    driver.quit(); }
```

AbstractTest

```
    public class AbstractTest {
     WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
     WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
     public void openBrowserFireFoxAllTcs() { 
    driver.get("some URL"); 
    }
```

Comment: Your framework should control the order of test execution. Or are you talking about one browser after another?

Comment: Yes I want to open browser - run TC - close it (it is one TC) - then run next TC, again open browser .....

Comment: OK. I have 3 TCs. All of them have @ BeforeTest (open browser) @ Test (do something) and @ AfterTest (close browser)

Comment: My TCs looks like this:
public class LoginFail extends AbstractTest{
 
 @ BeforeTest
 public void openBrowser() {
  extends AbstractTest{
 openBrowserFireFoxAllTcs();
}
@ Test
public void main (){ 

@ AfterTest
 public void quit() {
 driver.quit();
 }
///////////////
public class AbstractTest {
        
 WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
 WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
public void openBrowserFireFoxAllTcs() {
  driver.get("some URL");
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you want sequential execution. Open a browser>finish testing>close browser and then repeat the same for other browsers. If that's case I would do the following:

**TestNG.XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
<suite name="Suite" junit="false" parallel="false" configfailurepolicy="skip" thread-count="5" skipfailedinvocationcounts="false" data-provider-thread-count="10" group-by-instances="false" preserve-order="true" allow-return-values="false">
   <test name="firefox" junit="false" skipfailedinvocationcounts="false" preserve-order="true" group-by-instances="false" allow-return-values="false">
      <parameter name="browser" value="firefox" />
      <classes>
         <class name="com.github.tests.GitHubHomePageTests" />
      </classes>
   </test>
   <test name="ie" junit="false" skipfailedinvocationcounts="false" preserve-order="true" group-by-instances="false" allow-return-values="false">
      <parameter name="browser" value="ie" />
      <classes>
         <class name="com.github.tests.GitHubHomePageTests" />
      </classes>
   </test>
   <test name="chrome" junit="false" skipfailedinvocationcounts="false" preserve-order="true" group-by-instances="false" allow-return-values="false">
      <parameter name="browser" value="chrome" />
      <classes>
         <class name="com.github.tests.GitHubHomePageTests" />
      </classes>
   </test>
</suite>
```

**How I instantiate the drivers:**

```
package com.github.tests;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.ie.InternetExplorerDriver;
import org.testng.annotations.*;
public class BaseTest {
    public WebDriver driver;
    String url = "https://github.com/";

    @Parameters("browser")
    @BeforeClass
    public void SetUpTests(String browser) {
        if (browser.equalsIgnoreCase("firefox")) {
            driver = new FirefoxDriver();
        } else if (browser.equalsIgnoreCase("ie")) {
            System.setProperty("webdriver.ie.driver", ".\\drivers\\IEDriverServer.exe");
            driver = new InternetExplorerDriver();
        } else if (browser.equalsIgnoreCase("chrome")) {
            System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", ".\\drivers\\chromedriver.exe");
            driver = new ChromeDriver();
        }
        //Navigate to url
        driver.navigate().to(url);
        //Maximize the browser window
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
    }
    @AfterClass
    public void CleanUpDriver() throws Exception {
        // Quit current driver instance.
        try {
            driver.quit();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            throw ex;
        }
    }
```

**How the test run**

```
package com.github.tests;
import com.github.pageobjects.GitHubLandingPage;
import org.testng.Assert;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;
public class GitHubHomePageTests extends BaseTest {@Test
    public void ExploreLinkTest() {
        String explorePageTitle = new GitHubLandingPage(driver)
            .clickGitHubExplorePage()
            .getGitHubExplorerPageTitle().trim();
        System.out.println(explorePageTitle);
        Assert.assertEquals(explorePageTitle, "Explore GitHub");
    }
}
```

A global Github repo is available [here](https://github.com/safrrhmn/SeleniumTestNG)

Comment: Thanks a lot it is cool, but it is not my question. My problem that all my TCs runs in parallel.

Comment: @Alex and, you want to run them sequentially?

Comment: Yes, I want to run them sequentially

Comment: That's what my project does. I recommend you check out my project and see the difference

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<suite name="TestingSuite" preserve-order="true" thread-count="1" verbose="10">
    <test name="Test1">
        <classes>
            <class name="guiAndFunctianal.LoginFail" />
        </classes>
    </test>
    <test name="Test2">
        <classes>
            <class name="guiAndFunctianal.LoginAsManager" />
        </classes>
    </test>
    <test name="Test3">
        <classes>
            <class name="guiAndFunctianal.CreateUserTest" />
        </classes>
    </test>
</suite>
```

Comment: is it the same behavior?

Comment: Updated the answer with thread-count="1" variable. Try with this.

Comment: No, it did not help as well.

Comment: From XML file perspective everything looks fine. It should be some other problem. Technically when we mentioned thread-count =1, even parallel tests also should run one by one.

Answer (score 0):

Close your driver before quit:

@ AfterTest 
    public void quit() { 
    driver.close()
    driver.quit(); 
}